# How can I use mintty as the terminal emulator for MinGW/MSYS?

Tags: windows, mingw, msys, mintty

The default "terminal emulator" in Windows leaves a lot to be desired.  I see [mintty](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/) recommended as a lightweight alternative with specific support for MinGW/MSYS, but not much information on how to actually use it as such.

How can I instruct MinGW/MSYS to use mintty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mintty is indeed well supported by MinGW/MSYS; in fact, much of the configuration is already done and waiting to be activated.

1. **Install mintty.**  This can be done either at the MinGW command line or via the MinGW Installation Manager

   From the MinGW command line, run `mingw-get install mintty`.  It takes a few moments to download and install the mintty packages, after which you can exit the shell.

   Alternatively, you can select and install the "msys-mintty" packages via the MinGW Installation Manager.
2. **Configure MSYS.**  Next, you need to edit the shortcut you use to run the MinGW shell.  By default, this is a link named "MinGW Shell" located in the "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0" folder.  Right-click the link and select Properties.

   Wherever you find your link, the Target should be "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat", potentially with some command-line arguments following it.  If an argument selecting a shell is already present (such as `--rxvt`), remove it.

   Finally, add `--mintty` as the **first argument** after "msys.bat".  (Often, this will end up being the *only* argument, but if not, it's important that it be the first.)

Now, when launching the MinGW shell through that shortcut, mintty will be used instead of the Windows terminal emulator.